# Restrict class handler to content

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a user control with a single canvas in it. There will be a lot of shapes inside the canvas as well as other nested canvasses. I want all the shapes to react to mouse down events, so I can just identify the sender of the event and avoid an explicit, low-level hittest. But I don't want to add an individual event subscription for every shape.

I tried using EventManager.RegisterClassHandler but then I get events from all the elements in my application, even those that are not contained in the user control.

Is it possible to restrict a class handler to the content of my user control? Is there a different way to achieve what I want, that is more "established"?

```
public class GraphView: UserControl
{
    UIElement currentElement;

    public GraphView()
    {
        Content = new Canvas();
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        Background = Brushes.White;
        ClipToBounds = true;

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement),
            UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(contentMouseDown));
    }

    void contentMouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs er)
    {
        MouseButtonEventArgs e = er as MouseButtonEventArgs;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            currentElement = sender as UIElement;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit (follow-up):** It turned out that I actually have misconceived how the events work in WPF, which led me to trying RegisterClassHandler. After Andy's answer has pointed me to the fact that the object under the mouse can simply be obtained by RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource, I have just replaced the event subscription by the standard mechanism

```
MouseLeftButtonDown += contentMouseLeftButtonDown;
```

which feels a lot better because it was designed for that. The only difficulty was then that there are templated elements (Border of Canvas) that trigger the event as well. In that case I replace the current element by the canvas itself inside contentMouseLeftButtonDown:

```
void contentMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

    // if there is no parent, it's a templated element 
    // (Border), so substitute it by the canvas itself
    if (currentElement == null || currentElement.Parent == null)
        currentElement = (FrameworkElement)Content;
}
```

Comment: A routed event bubbles up. I would have expected handling mousedown in the canvas to only receive events from it's children. If this is a usercontrol, why are you adding a canvas as content in code? I'd expect to just see that and any event subscription for the usercontrol in markup.

Comment: RegisterClassHandler(typeof(__UIElement__)? RegisterClassHandler(typeof(__GraphView__)!? Derive from Canvas?

Comment: @Andy: I might be deriving from the user control and then I get a problem with markup.

Comment: When you derive from it, what's going to change? You could define just a control and template it, or a custom control. The latter would be my choice of last resort unless you're intending theming to change stuff. Something that's essentially just a canvas doesn't look like much theming will be going on but....

Comment: It's possible you might do better to use some styling to apply an eventsetter to all shapes. Maybe you could expand on your description and I could be more specific.

Comment: @Andy: using a code-only approach is the only feasible way for me as a WPF-beginner to get results in finite time. If I fast-forward to the future for, say, half a year then I might do things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this solution is aimed at someone who specifically wants to do this using code and doesn't want to know about styling, templating and commands.
It's not exactly what you've got because I want to demonstrate it not firing on anything outside the usercontrol and I don't want to try and guess at exactly what the intent is.
With all that in mind, this is unlikely to be an ideal way for an experienced wpf developer to tackle things.

My MainWindow has a canvas with an ellipse in it and a usercontrol. The usercontrol will have another shape in it.

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse Width="20"
                 Height="20"
                 Canvas.Left="50"
                 Canvas.Top="50"
                 Fill="Red"
                           />
        <Grid Height="100"
              Width="100"
              Canvas.Left="200">

            <local:UserControl1/>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

My usercontrol starts off with no content at all and the code is:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle { Width = 20, Height = 20, Fill = Brushes.Blue };
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 50);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 50);
        canvas.Children.Add(rect );
        this.Content = canvas;
        canvas.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Canvas_MouseDown));
    }
    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked me");
    }
}
```

If you want to reference the specific shape clicked then that is passed in the routedeventargs as originalsource:

```
    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Shape shape = e.OriginalSource as Shape;
        // Do something with the shape
    }
```

This is using an existing event.
Your code appears to be trying to register a custom routed event. You don't need that for just a mouse down.

Notice that RoutedEventargs is not as rich as the eventargs you'd get from a click event. But a shape won't have a click event.

When I spin this up and click the ellipse, nothing happens. Click the rectangle and I get a messagebox. This demonstrating the event fires for a child of the usercontrol's canvas. Only.

You might find the rather odd way the position on the canvas is set interesting. Canvas has attached properties for left and top which it uses to position any of it's children that have these set. They only have meaning to canvas and you can set them on pretty much any sort of piece of ui regardless of whether it's in a canvas or not.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview

Comment: With your approach the event always passes the canvas as the sender. When I talked about not wanting to subscribe the event for every shape, I have assumed that the sender is identified as the object that was hit by the mouse (e.g. a rectangle contained in the canvas). Of course I can do it by a hittest, but why when the framework already implements the hittest in the mouse event mechanism.

Comment: The sender is whatever object the event is fired from. Since I subscribe at the level of the canvas then it's the canvas. The thing clicked is the originalsource in the routedeventargs. I edited my post to include this.

Comment: That did the trick. Didn't know about the OriginalSource thing. Thanks!

Comment: You could actually make each of the shapes a button and template it as whatever shape you like. Unlikely to be your best plan here but you're clicking things and somehow will act on them so...  The "lookless" nature of wpf controls is something you will eventually want to learn anyhow.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29866.aspx

Comment: Nice tip! I have thought about something like that already. Is it going to impact performance because a button is somehow higher-level than a shape? I want to be flexible as to having probably several thousand objects (which is no problem with shapes) ...

Comment: A button is a heavier control but it will depend on what you're doing with them whether that is of any significance. The game map editor I'm working with places "trees" inside areas the user draws as woods. Each tree is a usercontrol. Similarly each wave on a lake or grass clump on a swamp.  However, these will all be rendered to a bitmap used as the background in the actual game. https://imgur.com/dyhuzrt